# How to change this pseudocode to C syntax

Tags: c, pseudocode

I've found this pseudocode from Wikipedia of Euclid's extended Algorithm, but I don't know how to return 2 values from a function.

```
function extended_gcd(a, b)
    if b = 0
        return (1, 0)
    else
        (q, r) := divide (a, b)
        (s, t) := extended_gcd(b, r)
        return (t, s - q * t)
```

Source:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: c or c++11?  This is important to what kind of "sugar" we can put in our answers.

Comment: ive edited, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template class `std::pair` could be used for this; i.e.,

```
if (b == 0)
    return std::pair<int, int>(1, 0);
```

Comment: or, since this guy tagged c++11, you might also want to mention tuples

Comment: Greaat , this worked. I didntkneww there was a way to return 2 things. It worked.

Comment: I got one last question, how do i do this ? (q, r) := divide (a, b) i mean how do i return that value?

Comment: The two values are the quotient (q) and the remainder (r). The quotient is what you get from integer division -- i.e., `q = a / b`. The remainder, you get from the modulo operator: `r = a % b`.

Comment: yeah , i finished the algorithm . But i got a stackoverflow error :/

Answer (score 3):

Your question is tagged both C and C++.

In C, you can't actually return two values from a function, but there are several ways to achieve the same effect.

You can return a `struct`.  See, for example, the `div` function, declared in `<stdlib.h>`, which returns a result of type `div_t`, a struct containing `quot` and `rem` members.

Or you can "return" more than one result indirectly, by passing a pointer:

```
void func(int *result1, int *result2) {
    *result1 = 10;
    *result2 = 20;
}
...
int r1, r2;
func(&r1, &r2);
```

C++ supports both of these methods, plus a few others. For example, C++ has *reference* types; there are also types in the C++ standard library, such as `std::pair` and tuples, that can be used for this kind of thing.

But before you start implementing this, you should decide which language you're using.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, on college we use "c" but they tell us we are using c++ cause c its a member of c++ . Btw sorry for my englis im not an english-speaker

Comment: +1 for for the comprehensive answer.  BTW Giuseppe, while some c code will compile without issue as c++, it is certainly not all so it might be better to think of them as different languages with shared features, because, well, thats what they are.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _tuple {
    int fst;
    int snd;
} Tuple;

Tuple tuple(int a, int b){
    Tuple ret = { a, b };
    return ret;
}

Tuple extended_gcd(Tuple x){
    if(x.snd == 0)
        return tuple(1,0);
    else {
        Tuple qr = tuple(x.fst/x.snd, x.fst%x.snd);
        Tuple st = extended_gcd(tuple(x.snd, qr.snd));
        return tuple(st.snd, st.fst - qr.fst * st.snd);
    }
}

int main() {
    Tuple ans = extended_gcd(tuple(120,23));
    printf("(%d,%d)\n", ans.fst, ans.snd);//(-9,47)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ive copy that code, pasted on Visual c ++ and i got this mistake . idk what does it means. or im doing something wrong? 

Error 2 error C2872: 'Tuple' : ambiguous symbol D:\Trabajos Visual\EuclidesStruct\EuclidesStruct\EuclidesStruct.cpp 15

Comment: @Giuseppe - try this at command prompt. >`cl exgcd.c /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include" /MD /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB" /LIBPATH:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\"` note:The path can be replaced with your environment.

Comment: or use Visual Studio command prompt (in Visual Studio Tools). >`cd /D D:\Trabajos Visual\EuclidesStruct\EuclidesStruct\` >`cl EuclidesStruct.cpp` or >`cl EuclidesStruct.c`